# Formating comments on code

Tags: support, code-formatting

Consider the following code snippet:

```
Observable.of(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

I formatted the code using the curly braces at the toolbar above, but the comment there is not styled well, it appears with the same style as code. I have seen the comment has been styled different (grayed out) in some answers. How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean syntax highlighting?

Comment: Yes, in particular, graying out comments in the program codes.

Comment: its because of syntax highlighting . use `<!-- language: lang-ts -->` or `<!-- language: lang-js -->`  before the block

Comment: @user2285236 no thats inline code. Not exactly what OP is asking here

Comment: The entire question doesn’t have syntax highlighting because none of its tags are associated with a specific language.